# Error message when using google contact api

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

When I try to fetch contacts from gmail, I received this error message:

The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you received this message to inform them of the error. A detailed error message follows:

```
The site "http://url.com" has not been registered.
```

May I know how to rectify it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering the domain with Google's API?

docs:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto#new

resgister url:
https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains

Also if you are making calls from http and not https you may be seeing problems there too.